# webpack not finding typing .d.ts files

Tags: angular, webpack

I used this import statement for type definition. It worked fine with SystemJS. But now I am trying Webpack and it's giving me problems at build time:

```
import {MyDef1} from "../typings/xyz";
```

build modulesError: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../typings/xyz in /Users/e/projects/angular2-webpack-starter/src/app/services

```
Required in /Users/e/projects/angular2-webpack-starter/src/app/services/my.service.ts Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../typings/xyz in /Users/e/projects/angular2-webpack-starter/src/app/services
```

file structure:

```
|-app
|--services
|----my.service.ts
|--typings
|----xyz.d.ts
```

Should I be doing something else with .d.ts files?